# TikZtree with asymmetric siblings

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Is there a way to define a (binary) tree in Ti*k*Z in which the slopes of the two lines of the siblings are different.

I want to generate a tree with the following appearance without positioning each node separately.

[image: Tree with asymmetric siblings:]

Answer (score 7):

I post this answer because the previous answer ([Sina Ahmadi's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475988/156344)) don't satisfy an important condition: **the slopes of the two lines of the siblings are different**.

---

#### Customizable code:

We define a new command `\binary`. Its syntax is as follows:

```
\binary[slope left=<num>,slope right=<num>,height=<num>] (<node>) to (<node>) node {<text>} and (<node>) node {<text>};
```

It will give us

[image]

Note that `height` is from `A.north` not from `A.south`. Improvement needed.

Setting to `slope left=50,slope right=35,height=0.75` gives us

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\binary[slope left=#1,slope right=#2,height=#3] (#4) to (#5) node #6 and (#7) node #8; {
    \node (#5) at ($(#4)+({180+#1}:{#3/cos(90-(#1))})$) {#6};
    \node (#7) at ($(#4)+({-#2}:{#3/cos(90-(#2))})$) {#8};
    \draw (#5.north)--(#4.south)--(#7.north);
}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\binary[slope left=50,slope right=35,height=0.75] (A) to (1) node {1} and (B) node {B};
\binary[slope left=50,slope right=35,height=0.75] (B) to (2) node {2} and (C) node {C};
\binary[slope left=50,slope right=35,height=0.75] (C) to (3) node {3} and (D) node {D};
\binary[slope left=50,slope right=35,height=0.75] (D) to (4) node {4} and (E) node {E};
\binary[slope left=50,slope right=35,height=0.75] (E) to (5) node {5} and (F) node {F};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Less customizable code:

The `\binary` is changed a bit, and the label of all nodes and the node names are the same now.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\binary[slope left=#1,slope right=#2,height=#3] (#4) to (#5) and (#6); {
    \node (#5) at ($(#4)+({180+#1}:{#3/cos(90-(#1))})$) {#5};
    \node (#6) at ($(#4)+({-#2}:{#3/cos(90-(#2))})$) {#6};
    \draw (#5.north)--(#4.south)--(#6.north);
}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\binary[slope left=50,slope right=35,height=0.75] (A) to (1) and (B);
\binary[slope left=50,slope right=35,height=0.75] (B) to (2) and (C);
\binary[slope left=50,slope right=35,height=0.75] (C) to (3) and (D);
\binary[slope left=50,slope right=35,height=0.75] (D) to (4) and (E);
\binary[slope left=50,slope right=35,height=0.75] (E) to (5) and (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a way that I can define for ALL parent nodes in the whole tree that the angles and the hight for the left sibling have a fixed values and the other sibling has another value. If I could write something like \begin{tikzpicture}[slope left=X,slope right=Y, height=Z] ... \end{tikzpicture} I would be restless happy :-)

Comment: Why don't you just use the `forest` solution? It seems simpler.

Comment: I'n not sure whether this solution meets my needs. I'm rather new to TikZ. Until now, I worked with jtree and pstricks which is perfect. But I want to present trees part by part in beamer, which is not possible with jtree, but --as I assume with TikZ. Now, I'm not sure whether the forest-solution allows me to present the trees in this way in beamer. The reason for this believe is that the tree structure cannot easily be interrupted by beamer-code. Maybe I'm wrong on that point.

Comment: @HoLo Check the site for questions on revealing `forest` trees in `beamer`. I think we have a couple of questions on that.  See e.g. [Using beamer overlays with forest generated trees](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/109950) and [How can I use beamer's \only in forest with scope on subtrees?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/417102).

Comment: @Alan Munn Thank you for the two sites dealing with forest and beamer. As it appears to me, there is no easy way to get the things done as I want them to be. jtree is perfect in this respect, but doesn't interact in easy ways with beamer. At the moment, I consider it better to use jtree for the standard trees and spend some extra effort, if I want to do beamer animations. So, thanks again for your helpful comments! Many thanks also to JouleV!

Answer (score 6):

Easy to do with `forest`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}for tree={calign=fixed edge angles,
calign primary angle=-30,calign secondary angle=60,l=1.25cm}
[A [1] [B [2] [C [3] [D [4] [E [5] [F]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forest` package. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[A
    [1][B
        [2][C
            [3][D
                [4][E]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

which yields the following:

[image]

You can find more examples [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf).